# CSS - Parallax Image not working

Tags: html, css

I have this whole section here:

```
<section id="design-centre">
    <section id="design-centre-cover">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cover-left">
                    <h1>Our Designs Make Luxury More Affordable</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
 </section>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
 section#design-centre {
    position: relative;
 }

 background: url(../images/design-center-cover.jpg) center top no-repeat;
    height: 800px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
 }
```

What I am trying to do is the following:

Have the image scroll when I the user scrolls, here is an example on what I am looking for:

http://www.hush.ca/hush-design-main/#hush-design

I tried using `background-attachment: fixed;` but that didn't work at all

Comment: You'll need JavaScript for this.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, it doesn't seem to be possible without JavaScript. Try [some](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-simple-parallax-scrolling-technique--net-27641) [tutorials](http://callmenick.com/post/advanced-parallax-scrolling-effect) for example code. The main premise is using either the vanilla JavaScript `window.onscroll` or the jQuery `$(window).scroll()` event handlers to detect scrolling of the main page, and reposition the background accordingly.

Also, next time you might want to [search SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240028/css-make-a-background-image-scroll-slower-than-everything-else) first for duplicate/similar questions before asking your own question.