# How can I make a background image scroll slower than the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Example of what I'm looking for here: https://www.98point6.com/

Is there a clean javascript solution that works? I haven't been able to implement the code I've founds so far.

Comment: That kind of effect is called `parallax`, and there are many solutions available on [Github](https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&langOverride=&q=parallax&repo=&start_value=1&type=Repositories).

Comment: [css-make-a-background-image-scroll-slower-than-everything-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240028/css-make-a-background-image-scroll-slower-than-everything-else)

Answer (score 0):

try this.  wscroll captures the scroll event position, and we can use that divided by something passed to the css translate property to scroll something at a slower speed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    $(elementyouwanttoscrollslower).css({
       'transform': 'translate(0px, '+ (wScroll/2)+'px)'
    });
```

}
}